# "Excel in" or "Excel at"

Tags: prepositions

Consider the following sentence:

I have always tried to excel in/at courses relevant to veterinary sciences, such as physics, biology and chemistry.

Which one is correct? A quick google search yielded no definite answers (it said both could be used, however, it seems to me some sources implied that they cannot always be used interchangeably).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would use **in** when talking about a broad field and **at** when talking about a specific skill.

> I have always tried to excel in courses relevant to veterinary sciences
>
> I have always excelled at diagnosing cancer in small animals
>
> I excel in laboratory environments
>
> I excel at using the mass spectrometer

I'm not sure if its wrong to use at/in interchangeably but using them like this ^ is what comes naturally to me as a Brit.

Comment: I think this might be correct. I for example have read 'excel in mathematics' and 'excel at outdoor sports'. Outdoor sports is more specific than mathematics. So I'd say it would also be 'excel IN sports'. Correct?

Comment: @FlacchusMaximus: It's more that you tend to *excel **in** a field of endeavour*, and to *excel **at** a specific activity*. But this is only a vague tendency, and in practice [we nearly always use **in**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+excels+at%2Che+excels+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), so my advice would be to just go with the majority and forget about ***at*** completely. No-one is ever likely to find fault with your choice of preposition, since any supposed distinction is just a tendency, not a rule of grammar.